# FB: How to get count of post according to date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make some statistics and I need to get count of all posts(not only posts of friends) on facebook on specific day via GraphApi. 
Any help appriciated

Comment: fql?q=select status_id from status where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())

this works for posts in friendlist but fb forces user to use indexes in every query, so it's not allowed to simply do select status_id from status where time > today_timestamp
any way to override ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only **search** through public objects with the Graph API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

This is how you get all **recent** public posts:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=*&type=post
```

BUT!

> The post search does not support limit/offset paging.

It means that you won't be able to search back through older posts for a given date using `since` and `until`.